# C programming adding values to string array and remove them

Tags: c

I've an issue with my c code which is about queues. So far;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define a_size 10
#define b_size 10
int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[] = "input.txt";
    char string[30], character,customerName[30];
    char customerA[a_size][b_size];
    char customerC[a_size][b_size];
    char customerE[a_size][b_size]; 
    int i, j;
    int endA = 0;
    int endC = 0;
    int endE=0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file");
    }
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %c %s\n", &string, &character, &customerName) != EOF){
        if(strcmp(string,"NewCustomer") == 0){
            switch (character){
                case 'A':
                    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                        customerA[endA][i]=customerName[i];                 
                    }       
                    endA++; 
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    for(i=0;i < 30; i++){
                        customerC[endC][i]=customerName[i];                 
                    }
                    endC++; 
                    break;      
                case 'E':
                    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                        customerE[endE][i]=customerName[i];
                    }       
                    endE++; 
                    break;              
                }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < sizeof(customerE[j]); j++){
            if(customerE[i] != '\0')
                printf("%c", customerE[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }            
}
```

wrote this piece of code. Content of input.txt is,

```
addQueue E Smith
delQueue C 2
delQueue A 1
addQueue E Jax
addQueue C Elizabeth
addQueue A Taylor
delQueue A 1
```

the question is that with the command comes from input.txt, I wanna add these values to array and delete them. It specifies how many elements will be added or deleted by numbers. If there is no item for delete it will print "-----". characters also indicate which group the names belong to. I'm new at C programming, really need your helps.

Comment: There should be a `return 0` or  some error value return in side  `if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file");
    }` other wise your `fscanf`  will fail.

Comment: the above comment applies in case of file you are trying to read is not present.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. BTW you should normally be a little more specific as to what you need help with. The code doesn't compile - do you want help getting it to compile? Do you need help fixing the bugs? Do you need help covering the dequeuing case? ... etc. In any case, I've kindly added some helpful tips to get you started in my answer below since you're new here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips since you're new to C and Stack Overflow.

In your code, `string` and `customerName` are already pointers. So you don't need the `&` (address of operator) in your `fprintf`. It is only needed on `character` since `character` is a `char` not a pointer.

Based on your input file, this comparison `strcmp(string, "NewCustomer")` should probably be `strcmp(string, "AddQueue")`.

For your inner `for` loops. Your conditions should be reading up until the end of input. In C, strings end in `'\0'`. So your conditions should be like this: `customerName[i] != '\0'` (*You can't assume how long the input will be!*). Also, in the same vein, after you copy over the string, character by character, you need to *terminate* it, e.g. `customerE[endE][i] = '\0';` after the loop is done. [*Side note: you can also use `strncpy` instead of all this*]

Finally, assuming you've corrected the above, you can greatly simplify the last  bit of your code that prints out the queue(s). Instead of looping through character by character, you can use the very same format specifier you used in `fprintf`, i.e. `%s` to print out the (null-terminated) string. So the code becomes as simple as this:

```
for (i = 0; i < endE; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", customerE[i]);
}
```

remembering that you loop up until the end of the array - in this case, `endE` is tracking this information.

Once you've actioned these tips, you'll be pretty much done; except for the dequeuing case which will be a lot simpler to handle.